# @microsoft/signalr modules upgrade from V3 to V7

Tags: signalr, node-modules

I am finding for documentation to assess and understand the chalenges or breaking changes associated to the @microsoft/signalr node modules upgrade from version 3 to version 7.

Please advise.

I tried searching for the documentation in the npm official portal.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr?activeTab=readme

but no clue about these change log and risk aspects.

Comment: What is your question?